# Проставить статус "прочитано" письму при помощи GmailAPI в С#

Tags: c#, gmail

Здравствуйте! Есть  необходимость получать сообщения с `Gmail` парсить и отправлять в свою систему. Вытащить сообщение получилось, но вот как поставить статус *Прочитано* не пойму. **Вопрос:** Как установить статус *прочитано* сообщению взятого из `GmailAPI`?

Comment: Вы можете показать, что получилось?

Comment: как поставить статус я не пойму, даже  не пробовал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = authResult.Credential,
    ApplicationName = "AppName"
});

await service.Users.Messages
    .Modify(new ModifyMessageRequest { RemoveLabelIds = new[] { "UNREAD" } }, "me", m.Id)
    .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

здесь `m` - экземпляр нужного сообщения (типа `Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message`)

Перед тем как задавать подобные вопросы, очень желательно [читать документацию](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify).